# javascript resize with mouse

Tags: javascript, html, resize, mouse

I'd like to let my users resize a div from the 4 corners or the 4 sides with the mouse.

I whish to use just Javascript, no JQ library please...

A tiny little resize image in the right bottom corner would be a plus!

Thanks

Comment: may i offer a cold beverage in the meantime sir?

Comment: Ha, 3 down votes! I can't see what is offending people with such a simple question!!! Besides, you are free to downvote me but please say WHY!!!

Comment: @DidierLevy what is your question? you are only requesting people to get your work done. You even start with 'i'd like'. This is a QA site.

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS3 `resize: both;`, as seen here: http://dhtmlexamples.com/2011/01/20/creating-a-user-resizable-div-tag-using-css3/

```
<style type="text/css">
    .isResizable {
        background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
        font-size: 2em;
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow: hidden;
        resize: both;
        width: 160px;
        height: 120px;
        min-width: 120px;
        min-height: 90px;
        max-width: 400px;
        max-height: 300px;
    }
</style>

<div class="isResizable">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
```

Comment: This would have been just GREAT... But alas its not working on IE! (I'm using IE9 mind you). I don't have anything against using Firefox, but the FAC T is 80 of my users are on IE... And I'm not here to tell them to change.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to work in all browsers, and I wouldn't recommend using it for production code because it's a new and unsupported in some browsers. I would recommend a jQuery library despite your objections.